# Sort a Pandas Data Frame based on group by some operation on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Columns line

Score

Country       Batsmen        Runs
India         Sachin         15000
India         Virat          12000
Australia     Smith          10000
Australia     Warner          8000
Australia     Ricky          11000
NewZealad     Williamson      8000
England       Butler          5000
England       Stokes          9000
....

....

I want to find the top3 countries with overall Runs. My Output should be

Australia            29000
India                27000
England              14000
NewZealand            8000

I am not able to find an exact expression that does it.

I tried this
Score.groupby('Country')['Runs'].sum()

This give me the whole output in a Series but not in ascending order as it puts the Country and Runs together as one Column.

What is the best way to Sort the Country on the Basis of overall runs scored by all batsmen. I see
methods of Grouping one column and Sorting the other, but here I want it to be sorted on some operations on the Runs Columns (sum here)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please use `df.to_dict()` and post the output in your question so we can reproduce your DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Country": [
            "India",
            "India",
            "Australia",
            "Australia",
            "Australia",
            "New Zealand",
        ],
        "Batsman": ["Sachin", "Virat", "Smith", "warner", "Ricky", "Wiliamson"],
        "Run": [15000, 12000, 10000, 8000, 1100, 8000],
    }
)
```

Pandas groupby with sort:

```
df.groupby("Country").sum().sort_values("Run", ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
               Run
Country           
India        27000
Australia    19100
New Zealand   8000
```